# How to create a new record in a custom object whenever a new event is created in calendar?

Tags: event, after-trigger

I am totally new in writing triggers.

In my org there is custom object called `meeting` where they track all the meeting details with contacts (like meeting time, meeting place, who all are attending the meeting).

Whenever they create meeting invite in google calendar for contacts they need to go to Salesforce and create a record in `meeting` object manually to track all the meeting details in Salesforce too. They have some reports on `meeting` object which they use it daily basis.

Einstein Activity Capture is enabled in my org. So events are getting created. But, they need to create a `meeting` record whenever an event is getting created in calendar.

I tried writing this trigger on the `Event` object:

```java
trigger createmeeting on Event (after insert) {
    List<Meeting__c> Newmeetings = new List <Meeting__c>();
    for (Event createmeeting: Trigger.new) {
        Meeting__c te = new Meeting__c ();
        te.Meeting_Name_CMQ__c= createmeeting.Subject;
        te.Prep_1__c= createmeeting.StartDateTime;
        te.OwnerId = createmeeting.CreatedById;
        te.Prep_Attendees__c= createmeeting.OwnerId;
        te.Account_CMQ__c = createmeeting.WhatId;       
        Newmeetings.add(te);
    }
  insert Newmeetings;
}
```

But its throwing the following error:

> createmeeting: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
> error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
> [Account_CMQ__c]: [Account_CMQ__c] Trigger.createmeeting: line 16,
> column 1

Comment: Hi, Does the event which you created had Whatid?  As the error says that Account_CMQ__c id null when trying to insert

Comment: Event.WhatId is an optional field on Event ; Your trigger processes every Event including events from, say Leads. You need to exclude in your for loop any Event whose `createMeeting.WhatId?.getSobjectType() != Account_CMQ__c.SobjectType`

Comment: Thank you for replying...I need to create a record in Meeting object whenever an event is getting created in Salesforce Calendar. This events will get created through google calendar since the integration and sync is on. when i created an event from google ,based on the contact i select ,event's Related 'what id' should get the account id rite? but its not happening.